# How do I traverse my binary tree based on user selection?

Tags: php, sql

I need to be able to select a node from my self referencing table based on the yes or no answer from the user input. It is a game of guess the creature. I am able to select the first node using "WHERE parentID IS NULL". I have two grouped radio buttons that the user selects and a submit button is then used for sending the response, the form action is GET. I know that I need to workout which nodeID I am currently on, and which one I need to display based on the radio buttons, but this is where I am stuck.

My table structure is: `nodeID`, `parentID`, `answerYesID`, `answerNoID`, `message`. The parentID, answerYesId and answerNoID all reference a nodeID in the same table if applicable. The first node has NULL in parent ID, any nodes that are answers have NULL in the answerIDs.

I currently have `answerYesID` in the 'yes' radio button, and `answerNoID` in the 'no' radio button. I have put in so many hours on this and I am going around in circles so any help will be most appreciated.

```
<form action="play.php" method="GET">
<input type="submit" name="start" value="start game">
</form>

<?php
$query = "SELECT `message`, `parentID`,`answerYesID`, `answerNoID`, `nodeID` FROM    `creature`";
$where = "";

function output($query,$where,$dbconn){
$result = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query.$where);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo("<tr>
<td>{$row['message']}</td>
</tr><br>");
echo"</table>";
    }   
}

echo'
<form action="play.php" method="GET">
<input type="radio" name="answer" value =`answerYesID`>yes
<input type="radio" name="answer" value=`answerNoID`>no
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>';

if (isset($_GET['start'])){

$where = "WHERE `parentID` is NULL";

output($query,$where,$dbconn);
} 

$current = &_GET['nodeID'];

if (isset($_GET['submit'])){

    if (isset($_GET['answer'])){

        $where = "WHERE `nodeID` ='" . $current. "'"; 
        echo 'yes';
        output($query, $where, $dbconn);
    }
}

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is failing to function properly?

Comment: I do not know how to retrieve which is the current node, and how to use the radio buttons to provide the next nodeID.

Answer (score 0):

**Let's look over your code:**

```
<!-- Not sure why you are using GET here when you are posting to the same page
     unless you have some bookmarking feature to resume later I suppose -->
<form action="play.php" method="POST"> <!-- Changed to post -->
<input type="submit" name="start" value="start game">
</form>

<?php
// Perform a query that gets information from table creature WHERE .. not sure why
// you are performing a query every time the page is accessed.
$query = "SELECT `message`, `parentID`,`answerYesID`, `answerNoID`, `nodeID` FROM    `creature`";
$where = "";

// output() takes the query, where statement, and connection to display the output
// in a table
function output($query,$where,$dbconn){
     $result = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query.$where);
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo("<tr>
        <td>{$row['message']}</td>
        </tr><br>");
        echo"</table>";
       }   
}

// display a new form that asks for a yes or no response, change to POST as your
// posting the data to the same page
echo'
<form action="play.php" method="POST">
<input type="radio" name="answer" value =`answerYesID`>yes
<input type="radio" name="answer" value=`answerNoID`>no
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>';

// Changed to POST as you are calling this from the first form on the page
if (isset($_POST['start'])){
// You are setting the where variable here for the query in your function
$where = "WHERE `parentID` is NULL"; // Grab only where parentID is NULL, not sure
                                     // what you are really trying to do here
// Send the connection, query, and where condition to the output function
output($query,$where,$dbconn);
} 

$current = &_GET['nodeID']; // This is passed from another page to this page?

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Changed to $_POST

    if (isset($_POST['answer'])){ // Changed to $_POST
        // Setup the where variable with the current ID for filtering
        $where = "WHERE `nodeID` ='" . $current. "'"; 
        echo 'yes'; // randomly output yes
        output($query, $where, $dbconn); // send data to output() for displaying results
    }
}

?>

</body>

</html>
```

It is unclear what you are doing with `$_POST` and `$_GET`, `$_GET` can be used if you are getting the data from another page and using the code you posted above to work with the data passed to it. Otherwise I switched it to post and left one `$_GET` for `$_GET['nodeID']`.

I didn't want to re-write your code as it would serve no purpose for your learning experience, this is not Stack-Codeforme, but it is a great place for you to ask questions on issues with code that is formatted and is working for the most part, yet you get stuck on something you can't resolve.

The code you posted is not well planned, unsecured, and should be re-factored with a logical flow. Think out the process in your mind and write it out on paper. Once you establish your queries and get something working, you should post here for assistance if say your query is failing or your code results in an error that you cannot figure out. Loosely posting a skeleton of your code for others to fill in the blanks is not a good way to get help, nor will it teach you anything.

-Skewled

Comment: The reason I have used "where parentID is null' is to find the starting node in the database, as it will be the only node  with no parent. The 'yes' output was there just to test that the if blocks were working as I was getting no data. I am able to extract the data I want if I code the nodeIDs into the radio button values, but I need this to be dynamic no hard coded. I am not asking for someone to write the code for me, but to help me with how I can get the values required from the user